# 0-999 counter in verilog

Tags: verilog, counter

I want to create a 0-999 counter with 3 displayer(abc) that shows the ones, tens, and hundreds in three displayers.

I wrote this program but there is an undesirable value between 9 and 10 and that is 'A'. I would be so pleased in anybody could help me to fix it.

```
module counter(clk,reset,a,b,c);
    input clk,reset;
    output [3:0] a,b,c;
    reg[3:0] a,b,c;
    initial begin
        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;
    end
    always@(posedge clk)
        if(reset) begin 
            a<=0;
            b<=0;
            c<=0;
        end
        else if(c>9) begin
            c<=0;
            b<=b+1;
        end
        else if(b>9) begin
            c<=0;
            b<=0;
            a<=a+1;
        end
        else if(a>9) begin
            a<=0;
            b<=0;
            c<=0;
        end
    else
        c<=c+1;
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is set up in such a way that `c`, `b` and `a` have to count from 0 to 10 before the roll over occurs. If you think over how your current conditionals are triggered to reset the counter, youll notice the value of the count has to exceed 9, ie, reach 10 for a cycle before the counter resets, thus getting an extra cycle of some character (in this case hexadecimal 10, which is A; as toolic mentioned). However, in fixing your code, youll want to be careful with triggering roll over events as switching all the conditionals to less than 8 will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all of your > to >= so the rollover occurs at the proper time.